# Good libraries for exponential time series smoothing

Tags: python, exponential-smoothing

I've a pandas series which contains the daily load consumption of a city for a year.
I wish to forecast the load consumption for next year.As a result , I'm making use of exponential time series.

The problem is apart from statsmodels' `SimpleExpSmoothing` , `ExponentialSmoothing` and `Holt` I couldn't find any other library which does this.

I work in Google Colab which uses Python 3.7 and the only version of Statsmodel which is compatible with Python 3.7 is 0.10.2 which has a lot of issues.

As a result , I'd like to know if there any other libraries which accomplish this task. (I'm too lazy to code this from scratch).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can code exponential smoothing in less than 10 lines:

```
class ExpSmooth:
    def __init__(self, a):
        assert 0 <= a <= 1
        self.a = a
        self.y_smooth = 0

    def smooth(self, Input):
        self.y_smooth = self.a * Input + (1 - self.a) * self.y_smooth
        return self.y_smooth
```

Then the smoothed values for each time step will be:

```
smoother = ExpSmooth(0.2)
smoothed = [smoother.smooth(y) for y in your_time_series]
```

You could probably use Pandas' `apply` method to apply `smoother.smooth` to each element of your time-series.

The Holt model adds one more smoothed state (so you'll have `self.trend_smooth` and `self.nontrend_smooth`) and a corresponding update equation. That should take about 10 quick and simple lines of code as well.

Comment: With just a couple more lines you can add the bias correction (keeping track of the product of all smoothing terms a used so far and dividing self.y_smooth by `1 - that product` before returning, so that (if desired) the series doesn't start out with a default value of 0

Comment: This looks great , just one doubt:
I've to forecast around 8000 values (all hours in a year) , but the above given code only computes 1 value , am I correct ?

Comment: @akshit.C, the part of the answer that starts with "Then the smoothed values for each time step will be" explains how to apply smoothing to the full time-series.